# How to Grab the Value of a label for a checkbox in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hello I am inquiring assistance on how to grab the value of a  Element corresponding to its  element using plain Javascript.
My HTML:

```
<label id ="label1" for = "vanilla">Vanilla
                <input type ="checkbox" id = "vanilla" name = "icecream">
</label><br>
<label id = "label2" for = "chocolate"> chocolate
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "chocolate" name = "icecream">
</label><br>
<label id = "label3" for = "coffee"> Coffee
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "coffee" name = "icecream">
</label>
```

My Javascript, Which currently returns either 'Null' or a BlankSpace:

```
var IceCreamBox = document.getElementsByName("icecream");
    var RootBeerBox = document.getElementsByName("rootbeers");
    var t;
    var j = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < IceCreamBox.length; i++)
    {
        if(IceCreamBox[i].checked == true)
        {
            
            j[i] = IceCreamBox[i].nodeValue;
        }
```

Comment: Which value do you mean? The value of the `id` attributes?

Comment: yes either  the Id Value of the Label or the Text That's Inebtween the Label Elements

Comment: `id` is straightforward: `IceCreamBox[i].id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to keep only the checked ones, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find their corresponding label:

```js
// Convert the HTMLCollection to an Array to be able to use forEach, filter, map
var IceCreamBox = [...document.getElementsByName("icecream")];

IceCreamBox.forEach(cb => cb.addEventListener('click', listCheckedOptions));

function listCheckedOptions() {
  var j = IceCreamBox
     // Filter to keep only the checked ones
     .filter(cb => cb.checked)
     // Map them to their label text
     .map(cb => document.querySelector(`label[for="${cb.id}"]`).textContent.trim());

  console.log(j);
}
```

```html
<label for="vanilla">Vanilla
  <input type ="checkbox" id="vanilla" name="icecream">
</label><br>
<label for="chocolate">Chocolate
  <input type="checkbox" id="chocolate" name="icecream">
</label><br>
<label for="coffee">Coffee
  <input type="checkbox" id="coffee" name="icecream">
</label>
```